# Pass an enum value to a method of a ComObject in Powershell

Tags: powershell, enums, com

I want to pass an Enum Parameter to a method of a ComObject in Powershell. The problem is, that I do not know how to create this parameter. The Signature of the method is My.ComObject.Method(EnumType, string, string).

```
$o = New-Object -ComObject "My.ComObject"
$o.method([My.EnumType]::EnumValue, "s", "s")
```

The code above always throws a TypeNotFoundException. I also tried to specifiy the enum as a string, but this throws another exception saying, that it cannot convert a string to an object.

What do I need to do, to create an enum value of an enum type that is located in the same COM assembly as the ComObject I created.

Thanks

Pascal

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$o = New-Object -ComObject "My.ComObject"

# Extract all enum values from My.ComObject and store them in $enums
$enums = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$o.GetType().Assembly.GetExportedTypes() | ?{ $_.IsEnum } | %{
    $e = $_
    $e.GetEnumNames() | %{
        $enums | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_ -Value $e::($_)
    }
}

$o.method($enums.EnumValue, "s", "s")
```

To see the numerical value assigned to EnumValue, use `$enums.EnumValue.value__`

Comment: That looked promising, but the problem is, that the Assembly property is not the assembly where the type is defined, but it returns the mscorlib, because the Type of the Object is MarshalByRefObject and not the actual class. Am I doing something wrong?